# How to Downgrade to another version of Addon?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I just published a new addon. How do I downgrade my addon version(3.20) to another version (2.80,2.90,...etc.) automatically from my script? (not via please don't edit again you changed meaning.) Are there any solutions or do I need to modify line by line? Or are there any standards?
I searched all over the net to no avail.

Comment: Blender does not support having multiple versions of the same add-on installed in parallel. I suppose you could script uninstalling the current version and installing another, but that would essentially be the same as manually doing this through the preferences as you would still have to specifiy what version you want to install.

Comment: Oh i see . Manuel edit is fine for me.  I was just wondering if we could do it automatically.
Thanks for the comment @RobertGützkow...

Comment: You can use `if bpy.app.version < (3, 2, 0):` and place your alternative code within the `if` statement

Comment: Thank you for answer @Psyonic. I'll do my best.